# Can not change session variable value after login in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Got a very weird problem in a Rails 4 application that session variables can be correctly set before sign in but can not after sign in

It is an old app with Rails 4.2.11 and Ruby 2.2.10, Devise 3.5.6 is used for user authentication. Recently need to add multi-tenant support by using apartment gem, due to some reasons, sub-domain approach is not used to determine tenant, but add tenant selection during login as well as tenant switch in UI. 
Would like to set the current tenant in session, so that it is available cross requests. But it is weird that the session variable value can not be updated.

The flow is

1. It works with omniauth, after login in the omniauth provider, the following callback method is called to set the current tenant and sign in to devise.
2. POST /users/switch_tenant to switch to another tenant.

Here is the piece of code to set the initial tenant during sign in, and it works.

```rb
  # /app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
  # the callback entry of omniauth 
  def <provider_name>
    # some code to check token, get user and default tenant etc.
    session[:current_tenant] = user_org
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
```

Sign in works, and the session[:current_tenant] is correctly set and available in views and controllers.

In another method to switch tenant, the code is like

```rb
  # /app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
  # POST /users/switch_tenant
  def switch_tenant
    tenant_id = params[:tenant_id]
    session[:current_tenant] = tenant_id
    Rails.logger.debug "New tenant in session: #{session[:current_tenant]}"
    # check authorization etc...
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Within this controller method, the session[:current_tenant] is updated to new value (according to the debug log). But after redirect, when opening the root path, the session[:current_tenant] is reset back to the original value during sign in. 
I also tried to set a temp session variable in controller like

```rb
  # app/controllers/test_controller.rb
  # GET /test/test
  def test
    Rails.logger.debug "session value in request: #{session[:test_key]}"
    session[:test_key] = "test value"
    Rails.logger.debug "session value after set: #{session[:test_key]}"
    ...
  end
```

The output is always like

```
  session value in request:
  session value after set: test value
```

Seems that can not set a new session variable, and can not update an existed session variable. But it can be set before the sign in...

I did some search, and tried following, still not working:
1) cache is disabled by setting response headers:

```
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
```

2) temply remove CSRF by comment out

```
  #protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

3) the cookie size is checked, around 1.2k, less than 4k limit

Had spent a whole day but no clue...
Thanks for your help!

[Update]

Current work around is to change to use cache store instead of cookie store, but still dont know the root cause. I think it should be config issue somewhere...

Comment: It's not clear where is the problem happening, you show that some variables can be changed and it's not clear on what code the session variable does not change.

Comment: Thanks! I updated a bit to add the controller and method names...

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the callback called by omniauth is run somehow on every request? check every place you set `session[:current_tenant]` and verify if it's being set more times than you expect.

Comment: I had greped in all code and did some log, seems not because of the callback called every request. I also tried to have a separate test controller to try set and get session variable, as the test_controller described above, the session variable is nil in every new request even though it is set...